# How do I return a struct from a function to a struct pointer?

Tags: c

I am creating a function for a code and the code uses the function that outputs to a file pointer like for example,

```
number *base6 = intToNumber(50, 6);
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int iNum;
  int base;
  char* sNum;
} number;

number * intToNumber(int nnum, int nbase) {
  number * theNumbers;

  //theNumbers= (number*)malloc(10*sizeof(number));

  if (theNumbers = NULL) {
    printf("\n\nNo\n\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  theNumbers->iNum = nnum;
  theNumbers->base = nbase;

}
```

Comment: Your comment is almost correct. But there is no reason to allocate `10 * sizeof(number)`. You can simply do `(number *)malloc(sizeof(number))`.  You will further need to allocate memory for `sNum` as well depending on how many digits you want to allocate.

Comment: Thank you! I am unsure about how to allocate memory for sNum, as the sNum varies in length depending on what the two other int values are.

Comment: Yes, you will have to figure out how many digits are in the number in the given base. This can be found programatically. You can find a solution for this online fairly easily :)

Answer (score 1):

You are beginning to think along the correct lines, but your handling of allocation for your `theNumbers` (you have commented) is just step one. When you allocate `theNumbers`, the pointer `theNumbers->sNum` is created -- but it is an *Uninitialized Pointer* that holds an *indeterminate address* as its value. (e.g. it points nowhere you have any ability to make use of). Think about your struct (`typedef`)

```
typedef struct {
    int iNum;   /* automatic storage types */
    int base;
    char *sNum; /* a pointer - hold address to something else  */
} number;       /*             must point to valid memory addr */
```

When you allocate for one of those, you allocate 2 integer values and one character pointer that have *automatic storage type* and can be assigned values. While `iNum` and `base` are integer values and can be assigned immediate values like `50` and `6`, `sNum` by contrast is a pointer and can only be assigned a *valid memory address* where something else is stored.

Normally, to make use of a pointer, you allocate a new block of memory, fill that memory with whatever is needed for the type, and then assign the starting address for that new block of memory to your pointer (`sNum` here). So now your pointer will hold the address of (e.g. point to) a valid block of memory containing values usable by that object type. (`char*`, a pointer to a char, here)

Your `intToNumber` function takes only `int nnum` and `int nbase` as parameters, so after allocating for your `struct`, you can only initialize `theNumbers->iNum = nnum;` and `theNumbers->base = nbase;`, but have nothing to size or initialize `sNum` with (it should therefore be set to `NULL`).

So you are close on your `intToNumber`, and all you need to do is return the pointer `intToNumber` after you have allocated storage for it (because following allocation it has *allocated storage type* which survives for the life of the program -- or until it is freed), e.g.

```
number *intToNumber (int nnum, int nbase) {

    number *theNumbers;

    theNumbers= malloc (sizeof *theNumbers);    /* allocate */

    if (theNumbers == NULL) {                   /* validate */
        perror ("malloc-theNumbers");
        return NULL;
    }

    theNumbers->iNum = nnum;    /* initialize values */
    theNumbers->base = nbase;
    theNumbers->sNum = NULL;

    return theNumbers;          /* return pointer */
}
```

Now what to do about `sNum`? Well, it's up to you, but for example, you could create a separate function that takes your allocated `struct` and a character string as parameters, allocate for `length + 1` bytes to hold the string (plus the *nul-terminating* character) assigning the starting address for the new bock to `sNum`, and then copying the string to the new block of memory, e.g.

```
/* allocate/set sNum member of n to s */
char *setsNum (number *n, const char *s)
{
    if (!n) {   /* validate n not NULL, return NULL on failure */
        fputs ("error: struct parameter 'n' NULL.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t len = strlen (s);        /* get length */

    n->sNum = malloc (len + 1);     /* allocate storage (+1 byte) */

    if (!n->sNum) {                 /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-sNum");
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy (n->sNum, s, len + 1);   /* copy s to new block of memory */

    return n->sNum;                 /* return pointer (convenience) */
}
```

(I suspect you will be filling it with your base6 conversion -- but that is left to you)

Other than freeing the memory when you are done with it, all that remains is a short example showing how to put it altogether. That you can do with something simple like:

```
int main (void) {

    number *mynum = intToNumber (50, 6);    /* declare/initialize mynum */

    if (!mynum)     /* validate succeeded */
        return 1;

    /* allocate/validate mynum->sNum, copy string */
    if (!setsNum (mynum, "created with intToNumber (50, 6)")) {
        free (mynum);
        return 1;
    }
    /* output values held in mynum */
    printf ("succeeded:\n iNum: %d\n base: %d\n str : %s\n",
            mynum->iNum, mynum->base, mynum->sNum);

    free (mynum->sNum); /* free allocated string */
    free (mynum);       /* free struct */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

If you put the example together, you would get:

```
$ ./bin/struct_alloc_member
succeeded:
 iNum: 50
 base: 6
 str : created with intToNumber (50, 6)
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/struct_alloc_member
==15553== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15553== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15553== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15553== Command: ./bin/struct_alloc_member
==15553==
succeeded:
 iNum: 50
 base: 6
 str : created with intToNumber (50, 6)
==15553==
==15553== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15553==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15553==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 49 bytes allocated
==15553==
==15553== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15553==
==15553== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15553== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

The full example used was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int iNum;   /* automatic storage types */
    int base;
    char *sNum; /* a pointer - hold address to something else  */
} number;       /*             must point to valid memory addr */

number *intToNumber (int nnum, int nbase) {

    number *theNumbers;

    theNumbers= malloc (sizeof *theNumbers);    /* allocate */

    if (theNumbers == NULL) {                   /* validate */
        perror ("malloc-theNumbers");
        return NULL;
    }

    theNumbers->iNum = nnum;    /* initialize values */
    theNumbers->base = nbase;
    theNumbers->sNum = NULL;

    return theNumbers;          /* return pointer */
}

/* allocate/set sNum member of n to s */
char *setsNum (number *n, const char *s)
{
    if (!n) {   /* validate n not NULL, return NULL on failure */
        fputs ("error: struct parameter 'n' NULL.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t len = strlen (s);        /* get length */

    n->sNum = malloc (len + 1);     /* allocate storage (+1 byte) */

    if (!n->sNum) {                 /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-sNum");
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy (n->sNum, s, len + 1);   /* copy s to new block of memory */

    return n->sNum;                 /* return pointer (convenience) */
}

int main (void) {

    number *mynum = intToNumber (50, 6);    /* declare/initialize mynum */

    if (!mynum)     /* validate succeeded */
        return 1;

    /* allocate/validate mynum->sNum, copy string */
    if (!setsNum (mynum, "created with intToNumber (50, 6)")) {
        free (mynum);
        return 1;
    }
    /* output values held in mynum */
    printf ("succeeded:\n iNum: %d\n base: %d\n str : %s\n",
            mynum->iNum, mynum->base, mynum->sNum);

    free (mynum->sNum); /* free allocated string */
    free (mynum);       /* free struct */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the actual question is exactly what is presented in the title:

> How do I return a struct from a function to a struct pointer?

The answer is that although a function can return a struct, it cannot do so *to* a struct *pointer*.  Under no circumstance can you assign a struct to an object of of any pointer type.  You can have a pointer to a struct, and you can have a struct that contains a pointer, but no struct is itself a pointer.

If, on the other hand, the question were about how to return a struct pointer then the answer would be "by using a `return` statement", the same way you return a value of any other type.  For that to be useful, the pointer you return ought to be a valid one, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass in a pointer to the structure in the function such that the signature looks like `void intToNumber(number *n)`?  And then you would have the implementation look something like

```
int main ()
{
    number Numbers = {.sNum = malloc (25) };

    // Do stuff here...
    intToNumber(&Numbers);

    // Do some more stuff...
}
```

Since you are pointing to the variable `Numbers` on the stack, you can manipulate those variable in the function `intToNumber` and have them available in the rest of the `main` function (or in whatever scope you decide to call it).